# Button input type in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How to insert Userinputtype 'button' from custom policy?
and how to handle the 'button' click on that?
I want to execute a technical profile on the button click.

I saw the button type is available for user input type in below documentation,
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Documentation/Features%20part%206.md

Answer (score -1):

You should just be able to submit it as:

```html
<UserInputType>Button</UserInputType>
```

Here's a good example: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/blob/master/Migration-JIT-sample/B2C_1A_Demo_Base.xml

Comment: Hi, I referred the above example link. But i didnot find  userinputtype button inside the policy. Can i get an example policy where user input type button is used.

Comment: HI, same here. there is no `<UserInputType>Button</UserInputType>`